# Are regular functions in SCIP callable in PySCIPOpt?

Tags: scip

I am currently using SCIP in a Linux environment and would like to move towards using PySCIPOpt as my research is slowly moving towards Machine Learning.

I have read the PySCIPOpt tutorial in Github as well as a document by S Maher and found them not being able to answer my question before I make the jump.

Will regular functions in SCIP such as `read (problem)` be available in PySCIPOpt too? This is because I have mps fils, pbo files and would not like to rewrite functions or classes that parse the file to fit them into the format found in Maher's document:

from pyscipopt import Model
scip = Model ()

x = scip.addVar(’x’, vtype=’C’)

y = scip.addVar(’y’, vtype=’I’)

scip. setObjective (x + y)

scip.addCons(2∗x + y∗y >= 10)

scip.optimize ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the commands that you use in the interactive shell? (there is no `read` function in SCIP).
All functions that you can use in PySCIPopt are wrapped in the `scip.pyx` file in the `src` directory of PySCIPopt.

So you can read a Problem with `readProblem` which wraps the SCIP API function `SCIPreadProb`

The code would look something like:

```
from pyscipopt import Model

model = Model()

model.readProblem('filename')

model.optimize()
```